# How to use function freopen_s

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

In order to read input from a text file, I wrote the following code:

```
int main(){
    int x;
#ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
#endif
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("%d\n", x);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

It works quite good.

However, in visual studio, the compiler gives me an error because of freopen and suggests me to use freopen_s instead. I try to understand how function freopen_s works, but I can't. My code:

```
int main(){
    int x;
#ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
    FILE *stream;
    freopen_s(&stream, "input.txt", "r", stdin);
#endif
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("%d\n", x);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

It does not output anything, and even the "pause" does not work. The cmd disappears right after the program finishes without anything printed. I don't know why the "stream" is used in freopen_s. Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: Even given that pausing is windows-specific, you didn't spell `pause` correctly so that's probably why it has no effect.

Comment: Your code works for me.

Comment: **Note:** For long I thought fopen_s() and equivalent were just useless stuff used by Microsoft to push for more vendor lock-in. But it actually has a key difference from fopen(): fopen() lets any other process access the file as they want, while fopen_s() sets sharing according to the mode ("r" allows other readers, "w" opens exclusively)

Comment: You can put `freopen("con","r",stdin);` before `system("pause")` as a quick hack, but this "solution" is awful (may break in unexpected ways in future).

Comment: @user694733 You're right. Rolled back. Ty.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I would suggest you to avoid using the C style I/O library and use IOSTREAM Library. Its more safe and clean solution. Here is the sample code which opens a file and reads each line into the "std::string" object and prints on the console.

```
int main() 
{

std::string  file =  "input.txt";
std::string line;
std::ifstream  text_filestream(file.c_str());

while(std::getline(text_filestream, line)) {
 std::cout<<line<<std::endl;
 }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to check validity of text_filestream? what if file does not exists..?

Comment: @Digital_Reality I guess he omitted the error checking for brevity (the OP had no error checking as well). You can check if the file was opened successfully through `std::ifstream::is_open()` and the stream state through `std::ifstream::good()`, `std::ifstream::fail()`, `std::ifstream::eof()` or `std::ifstream::bad` (all inherited from `std::ios`) depending on your need.

Answer (score 3):

I would give you an alternate way.
If you still want to use freopen, you can use 
"-D _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS" this option with the terminal command, the error message will be suppressed.

In VS you can add it under the following link -

Project-> "Project" Properties -> C/C++ -> Command Line -> Additional Options(Text box on bottom right).

This should resolve the issue!