# C/C++ reading line at a time

Tags: c++, c, carriage-return

I was trying to solve a programming problem of some site and this one had the following statement:

Read a string and parse it as a number, char 'l' can be considered as number 1 and chars 'o' and 'O' can be considered as number 0, commas and spaces will be accepted in the input but ignored, if any other character is found then output error...

So... since there can be spaces in the lines, I used gets (the documentation says it removes the new line and puts a terminator)...

My sequence of IF test if it is a number, then if its an acceptable letter, then checks if it is not a comma or a space... And I found out that it was almost always entering in the last IF even though there wasn't any character that should lead it there so I changed the printf inside it to print the

```
 printf("%d error", st[k]);
```

And it outputs 13: carriage return... I tried this compiler [here](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
     char st[100];
     char buf[100];
     int k, i;

     long long int num;

ops:     while(gets(st))
         {      
            for(k = i = 0; st[k]; k++)
                if(st[k] >= '0' && st[k] <= '9')
                    buf[i++] = st[k];
                else if(st[k] == 'o' || st[k] == 'O')
                    buf[i++] = '0';
                else if(st[k] == 'l')
                    buf[i++] = '1';
                else if(st[k] != ',' && st[k] != ' ')
                {
                    printf("error\n");
                    goto ops;
                }
 // remaining code comes here...

}
```

The input sample had the following lilnes:

lo6
234,657

hi
,,,,,5,,5,    4

2200000000

00

Should I use other function to read instead?

Any suggestions on how to avoid this damn Carriage Return?

The statemente for the problem can be seen [here](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1287) if you want more detail
Thanks

EDIT:

I'm asking that because there seem to be a difference between the compiler I'm using and the compiler the website was using, once I submitted a code that wasn't generating the correct output on mine but I thought the code was correct... and it passed. Then after it, I tried the code on a linux virtual machine and also correct but my gcc on windows failed... some characters were completely away from where they should be

The thing is:

Comment: are you writing in C or C++?

Comment: can be either... the options are C++ and Java but I often program in C and send as CPP (you can see by the way i declared the libraries)... I just use C++ for some functions in the algorithm library basically

Comment: Beginners should *never* use `goto` as there is almost always a better program structure. Get rid of it. As for your string, you should probably read it one character at a time.

Comment: Never use gets.  With no exception. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gets.3.html

Comment: I'm not a beginner, the problem is not in goto also. It says each line has length 50 at most... and this is a kind of problem for competitions so... reading a char at a time is gonna be much slower and still, I would end up in the same error

Comment: Don't be silly. You are obviously a beginner. Your code demonstrates that very clearly. An experienced programmer would not use `goto` as you have, and would never use `gets` (a *deprecated* function). Reading a character at a time would not be *much* slower. You simply don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: @WilliamPursell what would you recommend to use instead? could be a c++ function... any function that would read a line, stop at the '\n' and only save in the variable the chars that are printable in the screen

Comment: You may refer the following post related to reading the line from the file: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22048298/2724703

Comment: Ok mister know-everything... I ask you to read 1000 lines of strings of size 5000... you go reading characters one by one and you do (1000 * 5000) function calls (passing parameters in the stack, changing context and all that stuff)... and I make 1000 function calls (one per line)... your code is gonna be as fast as mine won't it? @ooga

Comment: Ok man, you know much more than me... do the test I said and use a timer on both cases, compare the results and tell me they are the same

Comment: @ooga why don't you try to send a solution to this problem in the website I posted? It is an easy one... but please don't submit it wrong (You don't have to show me your solution) =|

Comment: Any reason you're not using fgets to avoid a buffer overflow, even given the constraints of the specifications? Also, if it is sending a CR, it may be a Windows thing, so strip it out. On Windows, this would be done automatically by its C library with text-based input functions, but the same cannot be said of C libs on other platforms. After all, binary and text are equivalent on *nix-based machines, so it stands to reason that you'd still have it in your buffer if it was present in the stream.

Comment: @nightshade - Did `goto` die a very long time ago? Besides label this as C.

Comment: it is labelled as C, and once again... the issue is not the goto, the website has a feedback on how much of the test cases you got right and I had correct for 90%... when I tried to change the variable from int to long int it led me to 80% and since the website compiler seems to do things different from mine I just abandoned this problem for now and will try to solve others

Comment: `#include <cstdio>` is an error in C

Comment: @MattMcNabb I'm programming in C... saving as .cpp and compiling with a c++ compiler

Comment: @nightshade That means you are programming in C++

Comment: basically, but I don't use anything that wouldn't run in C... thefunny thing is that it might not even be the reading that is wrong... I changed a line that had "atoi" to "atol" and the type from int to long... and I was correct in 90%, it dropped to 80%... I think the problem might be related to some overflow/underflow instead of input... I mean, I still get the '\r' here compiling on windows but If I was covering 90% and when changed int to long this amount changed... I doubt the problem is the input... I'll try again later after I finish the other problem... been whole day on this new one!

Answer (score 0):

The preferred method of line input is `getline`. If you do not know the width of the input beforehand, `getline` will allocate space for you if you set the buffer pointer to `NULL`.

Since you indicate you have some experience in C, the following will show you how to step through an input string and parse it in the manner you want. While there are many ways to handle parsing strings, it is hard to beat assigning a pointer to the beginning of the string and then advancing down the string until you reach the null-terminating character (`unsigned 0`, or `char '\0'`). If you have any questions after looking it over, just ask:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char *buffer = NULL;
    size_t n = 0;
    ssize_t len;
    char *ptr = NULL;
    char *output = NULL;
    int idx = 0;

    printf ("\nEnter your string below:     ([ctrl + d] on blank line to end)\n");

    while ((len = getline (&buffer, &n, stdin)) != -1) {
        ptr = buffer;
        idx = 0;
        output = malloc (sizeof (char) * len);

        while (*ptr != 0) {
            if (*ptr >= 48 && *ptr <= 57) output [idx++] = *ptr;
            if (*ptr == 'I') output [idx++] = '1';
            if (*ptr == 'o' || *ptr == 'O') output [idx++] = '0';
            ptr++;
        }

        output [idx] = 0;

        printf ("\n  valid output: %s\n\n", output);

        free (output);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Enter your string below:     ([ctrl + d] on blank line to end)
This sting has 12345 aeiou AEIOU,,,,,commas, and 99, to end.

  valid output: 123450100990
```