# Still reachable leak summary in Valgrind for libcurl c++ code

Tags: c++, curl, memory-leaks, valgrind, libcurl

The following functions in libcurl saves a file and returns the http status code. However, when I run this using valgrind, it is reporting 0 bytes for "definitely lost", "indirectly lost", "possibly lost", but it is reporting **47448 bytes** for **"still reachable"**. I'm trying to resolve the "still reachable" bytes.

Are there any potential **memory leaks** in the code below?

```
size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream){
    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}

void connectAndSaveFile(char* url, char* output_file_name){
    CURL *curl;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl)    {
        FILE *fp = fopen(output_file_name,"wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}

string get_http_status_code(string URL) {
    CURL *session;
    session = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(session, CURLOPT_URL, URL.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(session, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);

    CURLcode curl_code = curl_easy_perform (session);
    long http_code = 0;
    curl_easy_getinfo (session, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &http_code);

    curl_easy_cleanup(session);

    std::ostringstream buff;
    buff << http_code;
    return buff.str();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. "still reachable" is most frequently not actually a leak
2. you might get slightly less memory reachable if you use [curl_global_init](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_global_init.html) and [curl_global_cleanup](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_global_cleanup.html)

Answer (score 0):

The most of the code mention above uses [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/). So I think we would have to look the documentation and read about API and what are the recommended steps.

However in the below method, client is passing pointer in which [fwrite](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fwrite) API is writing and returns back to the caller. This memory needs to be released in client(who would be calling this function) code once usage is complete.

```
size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)
```

However in pure C++ ways, we should use `std::fstream & std::string` so that we need not worry about the memory management. For more informtion you may refer to following link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22048298/2724703

Comment: his write callback doesn't allocate anything, it'll just write the data to a file that libcurl passes to it...